# Is there a way for an Android app to know the name of the APK which installed it?

Tags: android

I wrote a sample on PackageManager, but found only the dir of the app is provided, and renamed it to package-name related. But not the apk file name which installed it.

Is there a way for an Android app to know the name of the APK which installed it?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? And an app will always (well, 99% of the time anyways) be installed by the PackageManager, which is a system component, not an apk.

Comment: You might want to add why you want to know this // what your goal is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for an Android app to know the name of the APK which installed it?

No, sorry.